# Is there a way of making a simple change to this sorting algorithm so that it runs faster than quadratic time?

Tags: sorting, pseudocode

I have the following sorting algorithm which runs in O(n<sup>2</sup>):

```
function sortingArray (U, n)
//S is the array and n is the size of the array
//1. First create a temp array and initialize to 0
for i = 0 to n - 1
  Temp[i] = 0
//2. This is where it gets skewed - essentially Temp is used to store indixes for the correct position of U
for i = 0 to n - 2
  for j = i + 1 to n - 1
    if U[i] <= U[j]
      Temp[j]++
    else
      Temp[i]++
//3. Now Temp has the correct "index" order so create an array S and place the elements of U into it using Temp
for i = 0 to n - 1
  S[Temp[i]] = U[i]
return S
```

I have verified several initial unsorted arrays and it correctly sorts every time. The scope of this homework question is not to scrap this algorithm and write a well-known sorting algorithm. Rather, I am to determine if it possible to "simply" modify the above algorithm such that the time complexity is less than n<sup>2</sup>. Clearly what makes this quadratic is the nested loops but I don't see a way of using `Temp` in the same manner without two nested for loops.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Interesting question. What is your expected time complexity? A radix sort is O(wn), which this resembles. `if S[i] <= S[j]` should probably be `if U[i] <= U[j]`, by the way.

Comment: Hi, yes you are right, thank you. I have made the appropriate change. Also, I will look into radix sort. As for the time complexity, this algorithm runs in quadratic time (I'm not sure if that was your question, though).

Comment: Temp[] is being used to store the "rank" of each element of U, as opposed to storing the sorted indexes of U (where the final part of the inner loop would be `S[i] = U[Temp[i]]` . You could sort an array of indexes {0 to n-1} to U, using any sort algorithm, then convert the sorted indexes into sorted rank: `rank[sortedindex[i]] = i` .

Comment: Continuing, if the algorithm is restricted to incrementing elements of Temp, and since it ends up values 0 to n-1, this is going to take ~(n^2)/2 inner loops.

Comment: @Edward How much of an improvement are you hoping for (expecting)? O(n log n)? A constant factor? The proposed @rcgldr algorithm, for example, you'd discard the `/2` constant and you'd wind up with the same exponential time complexity I believe.

Comment: @ggorlen Any improvement (of any magnitude) would suffice. I also forgot to mention that space complexity can (and probably should) be worse. That is, I am expected to trade a better runtime complexity for a worse space compelxity.